# Colimit-preserving functors and cartesian natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I'm trying to prove the following fact:

Let $F, G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be functors and let $\alpha : F \to G$ be a cartesian natural transformation i.e. a transformation such that all naturality squares of $\alpha$ are pullback squares. If $G$ preserves colimits of a certain shape, then $F$ does also.

Let $J : I \to \mathcal{C}$ be a diagram. I figure that we have a canonical diagram

$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{colim } FJ @>>> F(\text{colim } J)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\text{colim } GJ @>>> G(\text{colim } J)
\end{CD}
$

where the bottom arrow is an isomorphism. I'm not sure where to proceed from here, or how to use the cartesianness of $\alpha$. How can I prove this?

Comment: You cannot write down $\mathrm{colim} FJ$ before proving that it exists.

Comment: I doubt that this statement can be true. Pullbacks have nothing to do with colimits.

Comment: I'm assuming that all colimits of type $I$ exist in both categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$. This statement was made by Tom Leinster in this thread: https://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/catlist/1999/algth-operads

Comment: It is *not* stated in this generality!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've refined my question to the following result.

Let $C$ and $D$ be locally finitely presentable, $F, G : C \to D$ functors, and $\alpha : F \to G$ a cartesian natural transformation. Then if $G$ is finitary (i.e. preserves filtered colimits) then $F$ is finitary as well.

This follows from the fact that filtered colimits commute with finite limits in locally finitely presentable categories.